# Programmatically apply knockout text binding to code-generated elements

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In my code, I'm using a data bound DevExtreme dxForm element and add a custom item template to that.

```js
formSettings: {
    formData: ko.observable(),
    scrollingEnabled: true,
    items: [{
        itemType: 'group',
        name: 'LabelInfo',
        caption: 'Infos vom Label',
        template(data, itemElement) {
            const card = document.createElement('div');
            card.classList.add('card');
            itemElement.append(card);

            const cardBody = document.createElement('div');
            cardBody.classList.add('card-body', 'lead');
            card.append(cardBody);

            for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
                cardBody.append(document.createTextNode(data.formData[`line${i}`]));
                if (i < 4) cardBody.append(document.createElement('br'));
            }
        }
    },
    // ...
    ]
}
```

The problem is, quite obvious, that this card element doesn't update after any change to `formSettings.formData`, because it is not data bound. Adding the data-bind attribute to the nodes added to the card body doesn't work as well, as they are not executed.

There are some ways to make the dxForm partially redraw. However, this is pretty hacky as my form is contained within a popup. My first attempt failed because the form is not visible at the moment of updating the observable and therefore jQuery returns an empty array:

```js
vm.lsl.formSettings.formData.subscribe(function () {
    // Refresh LabelInfo
    $('#lsl-form').dxForm('instance').itemOption('LabelInfo', 'visible', true);
});
```

My second idea was to call the redraw after showing the popup. However, this triggers only after all animations have been completed, which displays the card with old data for roughly half a second (which looks stupid).

```js
vm.lsl.formSettings.formData(result.packagingInfo);
$('#lsl-popup').dxPopup('instance').show().then(() => $('#lsl-form').dxForm('instance').itemOption('LabelInfo', 'visible', true));
```

Is there a way to either properly data-bind the template programmatically, or to find a better moment for redrawing the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. There is a function called `applyBindingsToNode` that is sadly pretty much undocumented, but it should be able to do what you want:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(cardBody, { text: data.formData[`line${i}`] });
    if (i < 4) cardBody.append(document.createElement('br'));
}
```